# Calling solidity contract function from ethers with uint16 parameter only works when the number is 9 or smaller

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, ethers.js

I have this code in my solidity contract:

uint256 constant maxNum = 10000;

```
function mintNewFull(uint16 tokenId) public {
    require (0 <= tokenId && tokenId < maxNum;
    // do other stuff 
}
```

And I called it using this code in ethers which worked:

```
contractWithSigner.mintNewFull(3);
```

But then later when I changed it to trying to mint with tokenID 11:

```
contractWithSigner.mintNewFull(11);
```

It didn't work. And I tried and every number under 10 seems to work and numbers greater than that don't.

Is it some uint16 uint256 problem? Should my constant maxNum be changed to uint16, is it impossible to call using ethers a function with a uint16 parameter? I have no idea how to pass in a uimt16 instead of a uint256 because I couldn't find how to declare parameter types in the ethers docs. It seems like everyone just uses numbers or strings so that's confusing (especially when I will later have to pass in an array.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this as not reproducible based on the self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!! Turns out it was something in the

```
// do other stuff
```

part where I was causing an integer overflow.

Yayyy I'm so happy :):)